# Javascript - multiple client-side validations on same event

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am performing two validations on the client side on the samve event.
I have defined my validations as shown below

```
btnSearch.Attributes["OnClick"] = "javascript:return prepareSave(); return prepareSearch();"
```

Pseudo code for

```
prepareSave():
{
  if (bPendingchanges)
    {
     return confirm('Need to save pending changes first, click OK and loose changes or cancel to save them first')
    }
  else
   {return true}
}
```

Pseudo code for

```
prepareSearch():
{
  if (bNoSearchText)
    {
      alert('Please specify search criteria before proceeding')
      return false;
   }
  else
   {return true;}
}
```

When `bPendingchanges=false`, I never get the second validation running.
Anyone who can quickly spot what I have overlooked here? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `return` statement will never be reached. Execution stops after `javascript:return prepareSave()`.

Looks like you want to return true if both functions return true - therefore, do:

```
btnSearch.Attributes["OnClick"] = javascript: return prepareSave() && prepareSearch();
```

Comment: That code will execute the validations only once, when the button is setup. You want to wrap then in an anonymous function or make them a string.

Comment: Why is an answer identical to three other answers the only one voted down?

Comment: Also I'm not looking to correct the way he is attaching the handler to the object (which could be improved), just the unreachable return statement.

Comment: Easy guys, thanks. I can now invoke both validations. Good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

`return`, as the name implies, returns control back to whatever called the code in question. Therefore, anything that's after a return statement

```
return prepareSave(); return prepareSearch();
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ e.g. this part
```

never executes. Try `return (prepareSave() && prepareSearch());`

Answer (score 0):

That's because the return prevents the second validation from running. Try this

```
btnSearch.Attributes["OnClick"] = "javascript:return prepareSave() && prepareSearch();"
```

Answer (score 0):

`"javascript:return prepareSave(); return prepareSearch();"`

1) You shouldn't have the "javascript:"
2) `return prepareSearch();` will never be executed, because `"return prepareSave();` exits your event handler

Try `"return (prepareSave() && prepareSearch());"`